# Overriding Cut/Copy/Paste in SWT Text control

Tags: java, swt, controls, overriding, copy-paste

**What is the correct way to override the cut(), copy(), and paste() methods of the Text control?**  What triggers the execution of these methods?

I have created an example application with a custom class that overrides these methods.  Unfortunately, nothing seems to execute these overridden methods, including the act of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or selecting cut/copy/paste from the context menu.

[image: Example picture]

Custom Text Class:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class TextCopyable extends Text{

    public TextCopyable(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkSubclass() {
    }

    @Override
    public void cut() {
        System.out.println("Cut!");
    }

    @Override
    public void copy() {
        System.out.println("Copy!");
    }

    @Override
    public void paste() {
        System.out.println("Paste!");
    }

}
```

Test Shell:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;

public class CopyPasteTest extends Shell {

    private TextCopyable text;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Display display = Display.getDefault();
            CopyPasteTest shell = new CopyPasteTest(display);
            shell.open();
            shell.layout();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public CopyPasteTest(Display display) {
        super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
        createContents();
    }

    protected void createContents() {
        setText("SWT Application");
        setSize(450, 300);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        setLayout(gridLayout);

        text = new TextCopyable(this, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }

}
```

My expectation was that the copy() method would be called any time that I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command to copy text from the textbox.  However, the methods do not trigger at all.  Is my assumption faulty?

Comment: It works for me on a Mac, as SWT uses native controls the behavior may vary between platforms.

Comment: BTW: You're playing a dangerous game by sub-classing SWT controls... But I guess you know that.

Comment: @Baz Perhaps I am not so familiar with what I should be fearing...  What do you recommend?  Is what I am doing here not practical?

Comment: @SouthpawHare Read [this](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#subclassing). It's in the official Eclipse SWT FAQ. I'm not saying that one shouldn't subclass SWT controls, but you certainly should know why it's not recommended.

Comment: @Baz I see... Well, these don't seem to bad.  It sounds like it's largely about portability.  We here regulate and demand specific OSs, Java versions, etc for our users, so compatibility isn't a big concern (in that we're totally okay with our program being unportable beyond what we already use it on).  Anyway, do you have any thoughts on the copy/pasting?  There are claims that the methods are called automatically on some OSs but not others?

Comment: @SouthpawHare It certainly seems to be OS dependent. I just tested it on Linux and it doesn't work.